# Onkeyup doesn't work in another function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

add image dynamically, but I have a problem when I input link in textbox images are not showing.

Here's a screenshot : 
[image]

In FireBug I see the following error:

> ReferenceError: toggle is not defined

Here is my code:

```
<script>
// Max Image
var maxSlide = 2000;
// Start Image
var curSlide = 0;
// Start Id dynamic
var Ids = 0;

function generateSlide() {
  // If Textboxt input link image, this id="img_dynamicid" src show
  function toggle(element) {
    we = element.value;
    document.getElementById('img_'+Ids+'').src=we;  
  } 

  if( curSlide < maxSlide ) {
    var html ='<div class="row" id="slideAdd_'+Ids+'" >';
    html+='     <div class="col-md-12">';
    html+='         <div class="box">';
    html+='             <div class="box-content">';
    html+='                 <form action="#" id="slide_'+Ids+'" class="form-horizontal" enctype="multipart/form-data">';
    html+='                     <div class="form-group">';
    html+='                         <div class="col-sm-9 col-lg-10 controls">';
      html+='<center><img src="../images/noimage.png" id="img_'+Ids+'" style="width:150px;height:150px"></center><br/>';
    html+='                         </div>';
    html+='                     </div>';
    html+='                     <div class="form-group">';
    html+='                         <label class="col-sm-3 col-lg-2 control-label">Link Image</label>';
    html+='                         <div class="col-sm-9 col-lg-10 controls">';
    html+='                             <input type="text" onkeyup="toggle(this)" placeholder="Link Image" name="link_'+Ids+'" id="judul_'+Ids+'" class="form-control" required>';
    html+='                         </div>';
    html+='                     </div>';
    html+='                     <div class="form-group">';
    html+='                         <div class="col-sm-9 col-sm-offset-3 col-lg-10 col-lg-offset-2">';
    html+='                             <button onClick="removeSlide(\''+Ids+'\'); return false;" class="btn btn-danger"><i class="fa fa-times"></i> Remove</button>';
    html+='                         </div>';
    html+='                     </div>';
    html+='                 </form>';
    html+='             </div>';
    html+='         </div>';
    html+='     </div>';
    html+=' </div>';
    $("#main-content").append(html);
    curSlide++;
    Ids++;
    $("#counter").html(curSlide+" from 2000");
  }
}
</script>

<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" onClick="generateSlide()" ><i class="fa fa-plus"></i>Add Images</button>
<span id="counter" >0 from 2000</span>
```

Comment: have you included jquery?

Comment: @Sushil He doesn't need jQuery. He has his own `toggle` function.

Comment: Define the `toggle` method outside the `generateSlide` method and try.

Comment: @Sushil yes, for generate slide

Comment: @JohnR if i put toggle outside function generateSlide
this toggle not get dynamic id

Comment: @MuhamadRidwansyah here you go http://jsfiddle.net/mpcgaort/ it even works if the toggle function is inside the generateSlide(). here's the updated fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/mpcgaort/1/

Comment: previously i try like this.
Doesn't work, TypeError: document.getElementById(...) is null

Comment: instead of doing document.getElementById('img_'+Ids+'').src=we;  try $('#img_'+Ids+'').attr('src',we);

Comment: i already alert done but
this images not change

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To be honest, you should attach events using jQuery. 
But if you want to do this way, you should put the toggle() outsite and pass the **id** parameter to it

```
function toggle(id){
    document.getElementById('img_'+id+'').src = this.value;
  } 


function generateSlide() {

// ...
     html+='<input type="text" onkeyup="toggle(' + Ids + ')" placeholder="Link Image" name="link_'+Ids+'" **id="judul_'+Ids+'"** class="form-control" required>';
// ...
}
```

Comment: i try 
but this image.src change "undefined"

Answer (score 0):

You are defining the *toggle* function inside your function and thus it isn't accessible in global scope where the event handler is tried to be executed. Thus you need to move the *toggle* definition out of the scope of function *generateSlide*.

It should look like

```
function toggle(element) {
  we = element.value;
  document.getElementById('img_'+Ids+'').src=we;  
} 
function generateSlide() {
  // If Textboxt input link image, this id="img_dynamicid" src show
```

Comment: Doesn't work,
TypeError: document.getElementById(...) is null

Comment: That is out of scope for this question since the function you wished is now being called. The problem lies in that the *'img_'+Ids* isn't found on your document. So there just basically isn't image with id *img_0* in your DOM.